# Error in StackBlitz: 'Unexpected strict mode reserved word' trying to use async/await with subscription.toPromise()

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-material, stackblitz

I have part of an Angular webapp set up on StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bx9vek).

In it, I'm experimenting with the best way to implement a mat-table with data coming from firebase with filter, pagination, and sort functionality.

In ended up writing a class implementing the MatTableDataSource interface called, `VideoDataSource` in './videoDataSource.model.ts'. In it, there's a method called `loadMatches()`. It is an `async` method:

```
async loadMatches(): Promise<any>{
    console.log("loadMatches entered");
    let results = await this.dbService.getMatchesV2().toPromise();
    console.log("results in loadMatches");
    console.log(results);
    let dbMatches = results.map(Match.fromJson);
    return dbMatches.toPromise();
  }
```

where `dbService.getMatchesV2()` in turn comes from an injected service and looks like this:

```
getMatchesV2(){
    return this.db.list<Match>('/matches').valueChanges();
  }
```

where db is a parameter of the database service of type `AngularFireDatabase`.

The `loadMatches()` call in the app.component.ts looks like this:

```
this.data = await this.dataSource.loadMatches();
```

where data is a parameter of `AppComponent` of type `Match[]`.

I'm getting the error, 'Unexpected strict mode reserved word', with reference to line numbers that don't make any sense (in app.module.ts; I imagine this is a post-compile line number?). The problem began immediately after I tried to implement async/await. The DatabaseService largely deals in Observables, but I figured the `.toPromise()` would suffice to resolve the problem. Any insights as to what is going on? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could remove 'use strict;' in your app.js as quick fix.

Comment: there are many syntax error in the model and service files and even one of the interfaces was not implemented correctly, please fix all and remove unnecessary codes

Comment: Thanks, @Reza! I've found a few of the errors you mentioned and am working to improve them now. Some of them have to do with the fact that I can't add ES2017 to the compilerOptions because AFAIK stack blitz still doesn't have support for tsconfig ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What's happening?**

The reserved keyword error is thrown by one of your internal dependencies.

**Where exactly?**

In `app.component.ts`, you have this line -

```
this.data = await this.dataSource.loadMatches();
```

**What's the fix?**

```
async ngOnInit() {
```

**Why?!**

Since you're using `await`, your function inside which await is being used needs to be marked as `async`. An await expression is only allowed within an async function. In your case, it's the `ngOnInit`. (Remember to do this in other places as well). You can read up more in [Typescript 1.7's release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-7.html)

**How to generally debug these problems?**

This is one of those instances where the problem lies not where you're actually looking for. So, a general check for linter errors (all hail linters!), and trying in different browsers can help. You might get different error and stack trace in different browsers.

**Alright! Alright! But does the error disappear? Does it work?**

Here you go - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmgbw7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Good eye! Thanks for the catch, @Vandesh. Makes total sense now. I don't really even think of ngOnInit() as a method anymore haha.